# Beginner Software developer - guidance for IT skills necessary for mobile/web development

Tags: javascript, java, web-development, mobile

I'm an electronic engineering undergraduate trying to pursue a career in software engineering.

My main area of interest lies in Mobile and Web development.

Throughout my degree, I've used the following IT skills:
C , C++ , Python , R , MATLAB.

And I might be working with ( Go ) during an internship soon.

I have a few android app ideas I would like to complete, and I need to know if it's necessary to pick up Java or frameworks (JavaScript+HTML+CSS).

Since I am pursuing a career in mobile/Web development, should I start learning the above or is it possible to design professional Mobile application with the skills I already have.

Thank you in advance for the help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Seek a discussion site, such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/

Comment: @Omar_MD a discussion site, such as https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/ is appropriate for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Throughout my degree, I've used the following IT skills: C , C++ ,
>   Python , R , MATLAB.

You do know basics of programming.
That is the first step.

> Since I am pursuing a career in mobile/Web development, should I start
>   learning the above or is it possible to design professional Mobile
>   application with the skills I already have.

Two dominant mobile platform are

- ios
- Android

  - **Android** 
    Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google. It is based on a modified version of the Linux kernel and other open source software, and is designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.
- Programming language: Java or Kotlin
- IDE : Android studio, Eclipse, intellij idea

ios
iOS is a mobile operating system created and developed by Apple Inc. exclusively for its hardware. It is the operating system that presently powers many of the company's mobile devices, including the iPhone, iPad, and iPod Touch. It is the second most popular mobile operating system globally after Android.

- Programming language: swift
- IDE: Xcode
  requires a macOs. Xcode is not available  for windows or linux.

You can start with one of them. 
Start by learning java or swift.
Then after basic or core features of these programming language. You can move to Application development in ios or Android.